# Neither set() nor add() django add to database entry

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following problem: I have a manytomanyfield (in model Toppings) and I can't populate it. I first tried using a list and set() and then I tried using just one object and add() in views.py but neither will return anything else than none. I have been looking at documentation and other forum questions but I just can't figure it out.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse

from orders.models import Meal, Topping, Order

def order(request):

    # Request should be ajax and method should be POST.
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        # Get IDs of meal, topping(s) and user
        idmeal = request.POST["idmeal"]
        idmeal = Meal.objects.get(pk = idmeal)
        # Topping[] is a list of numbers representing IDs for Topping database
        topping = request.POST.getlist('topping[]')
        for i in range(0, len(topping)):
            topping[i] = int(topping[i])

        user = request.user
        userID = User.objects.get(username=user.username)

        topping = Topping.objects.filter(pk__in=topping)
        print(topping)

        # Create object in Order table
        order = Order.objects.create(customerID = userID, mealID = idmeal, price = 12, status = "pending")
        # Add values to ManyToManyField
        order.toppingsID.set(topping)
        print(order.toppingsID)

        return JsonResponse({"success": ""}, status=200)

    else:
        # some error occured
        return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Meal(models.Model):
  meal = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  classname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

  def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.meal} ({self.classname}) ({self.price}) (id: {self.id})"

# Create your models here.
class Topping(models.Model):
  topping = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  classname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
          return f"{self.topping} ({self.classname}) ({self.price}) (id: {self.id})"

class Order(models.Model):
    customerID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mealID = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    toppingsID = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.customerID} has ordered {self.mealID} with {self.toppingsID} which costs {self.price} (status : {self.status})"
```

Comment: where do you get `None` returned?

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't get back to you. I meant in the console, it just didn't show up but Van Omsen's advice solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* setting or adding to your field. The problem is *printing* your field.

In order to print the members of a `ManyToManyField`, you need to all `.all()` (or `.filter()` or any other function you add to a manager), like:

```
print(order.toppingsID.all())
```

If you print a manager, it will indeed print `ModelName.None`. For example `Meal.objects` will do the same. It is by using `Meal.objects.all()` that you construct a `QuerySet`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying for hours, you're a lifesaver!